# Why is wxGlade enforcing a sizer as the first child for wx.Frame?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

I notice that wxGlade (gui builder for wxPython) is enforcing a sizer as the first child element for wx.Frame which seems odd to me since almost every book and tutorial out there suggests to use a wx.Panel as the first child element.

So if I want to have a wx.Panel as the base for my gui (for example to have a consistent default background color on Windows) I have to go:

```
wx.Frame -> Sizer (1,1) -> wx.Panel -> Sizer (x,x) -> Content
```

instead of

```
wx.Frame -> wx.Panel -> Content
```

Out of curiosity can somebody explain this design decision to me?

Comment: To me it simply seems a crappy designer. Imposing such restrictions is stupid; they could have added it by default but allowed the users to remove it if they wanted to suggest a "best practice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Robin Dunn, creator of wxPython:

*Personally I've been doing frame-sizer-panel-sizer lately because then
frame.Fit() will let the sizer calculate the min size needed instead of
just using the panel's current size.  But if you don't use Fit or
similar and there is only one child of the frame then there probably
isn't any other reason to need a sizer on the frame as the frame will
automatically fit the panel to the frame's client area.* - [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/frame$20sizer$20panel/wxpython-users/nW5NivkfU7M/-1ISbrYvvjYJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/frame%2420sizer%2420panel/wxpython-users/nW5NivkfU7M/-1ISbrYvvjYJ)

Another handy reason to use frame -> sizer -> panel is that it makes switching panels easier in that you can hide a panel and show another. See this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) for more information.